# Disable a sortable?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a draggable connected to a sortable:

```
$("#panelTarget").sortable({
    distance: '15'
});

var element = $('<li>Hello</li>');
element.appendTo('#panelSource');
element.draggable();
element.draggable("option", "connectToSortable", '#panelTarget');
```

at some point, I want to make it impossible for the user to drop items onto the sortable panel (panelTarget). I'm trying this:

```
$('#panelTarget').sortable( "disable" );
```

but I can still drop elements onto it, am I not interpreting the docs correctly?:

```
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-disable
```

how can I block the user from dropping stuff on the panel?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This event/action comes from the [`.draggable()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) side, so you need to disable it there, like this:

```
element.draggable("option", "connectToSortable", false);
```